# sh script does not execute but executable contents execute correctly on command line

Tags: bash, macos, unix

Below is a command I use to merge multiple .wav files into a single file named `output.wav` :

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <( for f in *.wav; do echo "file '$(pwd)/$f'"; done ) output.wav
```

This works as expected but when I add it to a script named `merge-into-one.sh` with permission :

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ddsasd  staff        93 26 Dec 11:50 merge-into-one.sh
```

and then execute using `./merge-into-one.sh` I receive error :

```
./merge-into-one.sh
./merge-into-one.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./merge-into-one.sh: line 1: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <( for f in *.wav; do echo "file '$(pwd)/$f'"; done ) output.wav'
```

Have I created the `.sh` executable correctly ?

Comment: What's your shebang? `<(...)` is extended syntax that `#!/bin/sh` doesn't support.

Comment: Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to ensure that bash-only syntax is available.

Comment: ...on a related note, naming bash scripts with `.sh` extensions is not good form. Better to not use an extension at all and encourage users to use the shebang instead of assuming they can run `sh foo.sh` (when your script may actually require bash, zsh, or another non-PONIX shell). And UNIX commands don't generally have extensions in general; you don't run `ls.elf`

Comment: try to mentioned sheband #!/bin/bash

Comment: @mahendrarathod, on MacOS `#!/bin/bash` is a bad choice since it uses an ancient GPLv2 release even if the user installed a modern bash release with MacPorts/Homebrew/Nix/etc. The `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang suggested above uses the PATH to look up the interpreter to use.

Comment: It's not a bad choice if you don't actually need the newer features of `bash` 4. (Yes, I'm using the term "newer" loosely :)

Comment: @chepner, ...granted, we're in reasonable-minds-can-differ territory, but insofar as Apple isn't exactly backporting noncritical bugfixes to their 3.2.x build, using it strikes me as a bad idea regardless. And even bash 4 is no longer the active upstream major release; 3 is downright decrepit these days.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for valuable information.